# assign command substitution output to a variable inside until test

Tags: bash

I expect the following snippet

```
until [ MY_VAR=$(echo my_var_val) ]
do
 echo 'inside the loop'
done 

echo $MY_VAR
```

to produce the `my_var_val` output. However, this does not happen. How can I make this happen?

**Long story**

I want to perform a retry on a script producing some output. I need the output later in the script. Unfortunately, assigning the variable value in the until test fails - the variable has empty value, when I try to use it later in the script. How can I execute the external script with retry logic and have its output stored in a variable that I can use later in the script?

```
max_retry=10
counter=0
until [ IMPORTANT_SCRIPT_OUTPUT=$(python very_important_script_with_output.py) ]
do
 #retry logic
 if [[ counter -eq $max_retry ]]; then
   echo "Failed"
   exit 1
 fi
 ((counter++))
 echo "very_important_script_with_output failed, retrying"
done 

python another_very_important_script_with_the_previous_script_output_as_parameter.py --important-parameter $IMPORTANT_SCRIPT_OUTPUT
```

Comment: What's the exit status of the Python script? You might be able to simply write `until IMPORTANT_SCRIPT_OUTPUT=$(python very_important_script_with_output.py); do ...; done` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
until MY_VAR=$(echo my_var_val); test -n "$MY_VAR"
do
 echo 'inside the loop'
done 

echo $MY_VAR
```

Answer (score 1):

`[` is an ordinary command, not shell syntax, and its arguments are processed normally. So `MY_VAR=$(echo my_var_val)` is just a string beginning with `MY_VAR=`, not a variable assignment.

Do the assignment separately from testing the variable.

```
while :
do
    MY_VAR=$(command)
    if [[ -n "$MY_VAR" ]]
    then break
    fi
    echo 'inside the loop
done
```